# mod_rewrite: match only if no previous rules have matched?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've got a large set of rewrite rules like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^foo foo.php?blah [L]
RewriteRule ^bar foo.php?baz [L]
```

And then I have a sort of catch-all rule that I want to only apply if the above rules don't match (e.g. for, say `/blatz`).  As long as I remember to include the `[L]`, that works fine -- but I've already had issues twice with accidentally forgetting it.

**Is there any easy way to to force my catch-all rule to *not match* if an earlier rule has matched?** (ideally, without appending something to every rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I can image is to either use the `S` flag to skip the last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^foo foo.php?blah [L,S=999]
RewriteRule ^bar foo.php?baz [L,S=999]
RewriteRule …
```

Or to set an environment variable:

```
RewriteRule ^foo foo.php?blah [L,E=FLAG:1]
RewriteRule ^bar foo.php?baz [L,E=FLAG:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:FLAG} ^$
RewriteRule …
```

---

**Edit**    Alright, here’s another solution that compares the current URL with the originally requested one:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ (/[^?\s]*)\??([^\s]*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}<%1?%2 ^([^<]*)<\1$
RewriteRule …
```

But I think that requires at least Apache 2 because Apache 1.x used POSIX ERE and POSIX ERE don’t support the `\`*`n`* backreferences in the pattern.

Comment: Ah hah!  The "make sure the URL hasn't already changed" solution is clever.